# const variable as non-type template parameter (VARIABLE cannot appear in a constant-expression)

Tags: c++, templates, constants

Why does this work?

```
char __nontype[] = "foo";
typedef TemplateClass<T, __nontype> MyClass;
```

But this (with a  constant variable) not?

```
const char __nontype[] = "foo";
typedef TemplateClass<T, __nontype> MyClass;
```

Compiler Error:

error: ‘__nontype’ cannot appear in a constant-expression

error: template argument 2 is invalid

Comment: That might depend on the definition of TemplateClass<>.  Can you post that?

Comment: I think the fundamental misunderstanding here is that you assume the `const` modifier automatically makes something a `constexpr`. Char arrays are not compile-time constants; they are not known until link time.

Comment: @tenfour You're missing that with a `char` array, it works. That's because some link-time constant expressions are valid template arguments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is because `const` affects the linkage. It works if you add `extern`. That said, as far as I can tell:

> 14.3.2 Template non-type arguments [temp.arg.nontype]
>
> A template-argument for a non-type, non-template template-parameter shall be one of:
>
> - an integral constant expression (including a constant expression of literal class type that can be used as an integral constant expression as described in 5.19); or
> - the name of a non-type template-parameter; or
> - a constant expression (5.19) that designates the address of an object with static storage duration and external or internal linkage or a function with external or internal linkage, including function templates and function template-ids but excluding non-static class members, expressed (ignoring parentheses) as & id-expression, except that the & may be omitted if the name refers to a function or array and shall be omitted if the corresponding template-parameter is a reference; or
> - a constant expression that evaluates to a null pointer value (4.10); or
> - a constant expression that evaluates to a null member pointer value (4.11); or
> - a pointer to member expressed as described in 5.3.1.

it should also work without `extern`. The object is allowed to have internal linkage, but your compiler does not yet support that. This is one of the changes in C++11, the previous C++ standard did not allow it.

Comment: Ok, this seems to be the problem. Good answer!As far as i've noticed now, allowing internal linkage is new (c++11?). But why was it not allowed?

Comment: @ejoerns I do not know whether this is the whole reason, but only allowing objects and functions with external linkage makes it easier to ensure that all mangled names of distinct template instantiations differ.

Comment: @ejoerns You're right that it's new in C++11, by the way. I just checked.

Answer (score 1):

The error says it: the result is not a constant expression (it is known at link time, but not compile time).

Here is an example that *would* work:

```
typedef const char *nontype_t;
template <nontype_t> struct Y {};

char hello[] = "hello";
constexpr char* world = hello;

int main()
{
    Y<hello> a;
}
```

Comment: I don't get it. How is pointer-to-char any more a pointer to object than pointer-to-const-char?

Comment: Then why did you cite the part of the standard that deals with which types are acceptable?

Comment: It may be an object with static storage duration, and depending on the type of the template parameter, then it would be valid.  The problem is likely that the type of the parameter is an array with non const char type.

Comment: @sehe That still doesn't explain the difference between const and non-const, because you're still defining a modifiable char array, even though you're converting it (indirectly) to a pointer-to-const-char. As far as I can tell (see my answer), there shouldn't be any difference.